# Как реализовать сортировку по фамилии человека и его суммы оплаты в консоли

Tags: java, классы, методы

Как реализовать сортировку по фамилиям абонентов и по сумме оплаты? Консольное приложение

Comment: Реализовать сортировку _чего_?  В виде чего представлены данные: строки/объекты/массивы/списки?  Что уже пытались сделать, и что не получилось?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос максимально неграмотный -_-

Коллекцию из строк по алфавиту - Collections.sort(*коллекция строк*);
Массив - Arrays.sort(*массив строк*);

Численные - так же абсолютно...
Логику/порядок сортировки прикручивай в зависимости от своей задачи..

Если хочешь ручками реализовывать алгоритмы сортировки - по первой ссылке в гугле https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/. Максимально понятный для новичка алгоритм. Погугли quick sort, heap sort, если хочешь поинтереснее (и, разумеется, побыстрее)

Comment: Это понятно. Но как мне связать человека с его суммой? И при этом сортировать

Comment: Что означает связать? И тем более что значит "при этом сортировать"? 
В бд, к примеру, в таблицах в каждой записи поля однозначно связаны априори. Как они в твоем случае храняться - не имею ни малейшего представления... Можешь хранить как хэшмапу (но берегись коллизий - фамилия Иванов очень распространенная). Можешь как класс хранить class Human { String surname; Double money; }... На что фантазии хватит, как говориться!

Comment: попробуйте прикрепить код , а мы поправим и все получится